# how to securely store Masterkey in the application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, password-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have a spring boot java application in which all of the necessary data including clients' passwords, P12 passwords, ... are encrypted by the Masterkey.
**The encryption type is Symmetric.**
At the start point of the application, the operator should enter the Masterkey. On the other hand, Operators want to run the app as a service so that when the app is stopped for any reason, the Operation System is able to run the application automatically.

*A bad solution is to store plaintext MasterKey in a file. (Bad Solution)*

*A good solution is to store plaintext MasterKey in an HSM device. But it is not possible for me at the moment.*

**Is there a good solution for storing Masterkey and passing it to the app in the startup of the application?**

Comment: Secure from whom? If your application can read the master key, then so can anyone else with the same permissions (and certainly the owner of the device). There's no way around that. At best you can make it harder (via obfuscation), but you can't make it impossible.

Comment: to secure from anyone who wants to attack an application. If the attacker gets into the server he easily can read the MasterKey from the file which contains plainText MasterKey. on the other hand we do not want to force system admin to enter MasterKey on the console or application prompt manually.